# Circle with transparent borders over background

Tags: html, css, transparency

How can I achieve such a thing in CSS?

[image: Target]

I've tried so many ways but the dark background is still in the way and can't be clipped so the background image under it's invisible...

```css
.item {
  position: relative;
}
    
.item:before {
  content: '';
  size(100%);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0,0 0.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
   <img>
   <span class="rate">
     <span class="amount">10</span> امتیاز
   </span>
</div>
```

I'm looking for a way to be able to make parts of the dark background transparent, so the image can be seen.

Comment: One alternative: Use a radial gradient to create the overlay effect, that way you get the same effect without having to rely on any new and questionably-supported browser features.

Comment: Radial gradient for the circle or the background?

Comment: For the dark overlay, I'll put together an example in an answer.

Comment: you want to reward an existing answer or you are not satisfied with any of the current answers?

Answer (score 9):

This can be achieved using a radial gradient, (Example split onto separate lines to make it easier to read)

```
background-image: radial-gradient(
   /* Position the circle at the center, 40px from the top */
  circle at center 40px,
  /* The center of the radius should be dark */
  rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 0%,
  /* This is the inner edge of the circle, we transition from dark-transparent between pixels 30 and 31 */
  rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 30px, rgba(0,0,0,0) 31px, 
  /* This is the outer edge of the circle, we transition back from transprent-dark between pixels 34 and 35*/
  rgba(0,0,0,0) 34px, rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 35px,  
  /* Everything outside of the circle should be dark */
  rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 100%
);
```

Where `circle at center 40px` defines the position of the circle relative to the parent element (Horizontally centred, an 40px down from the top) bare in mind this is the position for the centre of the circle so you do need to account for it's radius.

And we use very small steps between the gradient to make it look like a solid line rather than a blurred gradient (I find that a `1px` difference helps prevent aliasing on the line and makes everything look much smoother)

You can adjust the size of the circle or the thickness of the line by changing the `30px`, `31px`, `34px` and `35px` values in the gradient.

Working example:

```css
.item {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/200);
}

.item:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  /* This is the ring itself, you can adjust it's size using the pixel values, leaving 1px differnce usually leaves the best result for smooth edges */
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at center 40px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 30px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 31px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 34px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 35px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="item"></div>
```

(This method is browser [compatible](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-css_properties_background-image_gradients) with pretty much every browser released since 2010)

Answer (score 5):

Infinite `box-shadow` with `overflow: hidden;` I don't know if it would work for you, I just tried-

```html
<style>
  .item img {
    max-width: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
  }

  .item {
    font-family: 'Amiri', serif;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    overflow: hidden; /* STEP-1 */
    position: relative;
  }

  .rate {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;

    border-radius: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
    top: 80px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translatex(-50%);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #fff;
  }

  .rate::before {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    width: calc(100% + 10px);
    height: calc(100% + 10px);
    top: -5px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translatex(-50%);
    border-radius: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 100vh rgba(0,0,0,.7); /* STEP-2 */
  }

  .amount {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 700;
    display: block;
  }
</style>



<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Amiri:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="item">
   <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/4888690/pexels-photo-4888690.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940" alt="Card title">
   <span class="rate">
     <span class="amount">١٠</span> امتیاز
   </span>
</div>
```

Comment: [Just found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14061104/css3-box-shadow-size-percent-units) out that the value of spread in `box-shadow` can have `vw` and `vh` units, so I updated my demo, it means the trick in this demo is more dynamic than before.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a few divs with `position: absolute`:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.bg {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url('https://i.ytimg.com/vi/fqumdSlyLxg/maxresdefault.jpg');
  filter: brightness(0.4);
}

.circle {
  position: absolute;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  backdrop-filter: brightness(5);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: brightness(5);
  z-index: 0;
}

.inner-circle {
  position: absolute;
  height: 142px;
  width: 142px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  backdrop-filter: brightness(0.2);
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: brightness(0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.rate {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  position: absolute;
  height: 142px;
  color: white;
  z-index: 2;
}

.amount {
  font-size: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="bg"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="inner-circle"></div>
  <div class="rate">
    <span class="amount">10</span>
    <span class="amount">امتیاز</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Use the `backdrop-filter` property to set the brightness and `display: flex` on the container to center everything, then for the text use `text-shadow` to make it luminous.

Comment: Looks nice, unfortunately only about 50% global support for `backdrop-filter`. Know an alternative to get the same effect?

Comment: Added the `-webkit-` prefix which means it works in Safari, Edge, Chrome and Opera. Just Firefox and IE that don't seem to like it.

Comment: Good thing you did, but I guess it'll be some while for the property to kick in. Have a look at my alternative...and shoot at it ;-)... Uses `background-blend-mode` and transparent colors.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, I made `.item` and its child elements Flexbox containers for easy positioning.

The circle is simply a circular element with a border.

All you have to do now is fiddle with sizes, colors and tranparency.

For the fun of it I added some `:hover` effects...

**snippet** with comments

```css
/* All are FBL containers, for easy positioning */
.item, .item>*, .rate {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center; align-items: center;
}
.rate { flex-direction: column }

/* item content */
.item {
    position: relative; /* position child elements to this parent */
    width: 400px;
    height: 600px;

    /* set image to background of item */
    background-image: url("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/fqumdSlyLxg/maxresdefault.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;             /* clip/stretch when too large/small */

    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);  /* some tranparent black */
    background-blend-mode: overlay;     /* mix bg-color with image */

    /* eye-candy */
    margin: 5rem auto; /* center */

    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,.6);
    border-radius: 12px;
}

.item>* {
    position: absolute; /* position child inside parent */
    width : 100px; height: 100px;
    
    opacity: 0.7;
}

.rate { text-shadow: 0px 0px 7px rgba(255,255,255,.8) }

.circle { 
    border: 5px solid rgba(255,255,255,.3);
    border-radius: 50%;

    filter: blur(1px);
}

/******************************/
/* HOVER eye-candy, demo only */
/******************************/
.item:hover {
    background-blend-mode: normal;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
}

.item:hover>* {
    opacity: 1;
}
.item:hover .circle {
    border-color: rgba(255,255,255,.8);
}


/* demo eye-candy */
.item {
    /* GMC elevation 1dp */
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 1px -1px rgba(0,0,0,.20),
                0px 1px 1px  0px rgba(0,0,0,.14),
                0px 1px 3px  0px rgba(0,0,0,.12);
}
.item:hover {
    transform: scale(1.01);
    /* GMC elevation 3dp */
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px -2px rgba(0,0,0,.20),
                0px 3px 4px  0px rgba(0,0,0,.14),
                0px 1px 8px  0px rgba(0,0,0,.12);
}
/*.item:active:not(:focus) { transform: scale(1) }/* enable for some animation */
```

```html
<div class="item">
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="rate">
        <span class="amount">10</span>
        <span>text</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: nice but it's not transparent you can't visibily see the backgound image

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but this works fine in FF, Chrome and Edge [so63035636-1.jpg](https://i.postimg.cc/W1GqBn9n/so63035636-1.jpg)

Comment: See the screenshot in first post, the point here is that the circle must cut the dark backgound, it's like we searate a circle from dark bg

Comment: With all the blur and opacity eye-candy I made, it is hard to see that the circle and text *do* get cut out as you meant. I'll adjust the snippet and make the effect more clear. With `background-blend-mode` and `mix-blend-mode` you can use colors *black* (with overlay,multiply) and *white* (with screen,hard-light,soft-light) to enhance/degrade the darkness and lightness of an element (or image), comparable with *layer-mask* in Photoshop or *Dodge&Burn* in ol'skool photo development. The blend modes are very powerfull, but many people don't know how to use them. I'll get back, with a mini tut.